# Await Firestore collection to be done before applying listener

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I can't call the function "createNewContent" with async since i get the error: "async call in a function that does not support concurrency" from the function that calls this one.

How can i however wait until the Firestore call is done before applying the Firestore listener?

Process i need:

1: Call Firestore function and grab all data.

2: Apply listener after step 1 is done.

3: Call function again but this time start by resetting listener.

```
   private var firestoreListener: ListenerRegistration?
    
   func createNewContent(firebasePath: Query) {
       self.firestoreListener?.remove()

       let contentRef = firebasePath
       contentRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
           if err == nil && querySnapshot != nil {
               if querySnapshot!.documents.count == 0 {
                   for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                       //Firestore Data...
                   }
               }
           }
        }
       contentUpdates(firebasePath: firebasePath)
     }
    func contentUpdates(firebasePath: Query) {
        firestoreListener = firebasePath.addSnapshotListener() { [self] (querySnapshot, err) in
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
                print("Error fetching snapshots: \(err!)")
                return
            }
            snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
                if (diff.type == .added) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the Firebase async/await functions (no closures) it is much simpler to keep things in order. Just retype the method again your functions will have to be decorated with “async throws” too.

Comment: Could you help a bit with that if possible. I'm a bit confused on how it should be done unfortunately.

Comment: It is hard to help with the little code you have, have you looked into `FirestoreQuery`? if you are adopting `async await` and `FirestoreSwift` it does all of this for you

Comment: Do you perhaps have any resources or examples i can look at?

Comment: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firestorequery-swiftui-the-easiest-way-to-listen-for-real-time-updates-32f436cfa26b